# I'm trying to work with graphics and make it move though a timer but it wont move

Tags: c#, graphics

```
class Class1
{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Class1(int a,int b, int x, int y)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value; }
    }
    public int B
    {
        get { return b; }
        set { b = value; }
    }
    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }
    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value; }
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Class1> listan = new List<Class1>();
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 16);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.DeepSkyBlue);

        Class1 classen = new Class1(new Random().Next(3,12), new Random().Next(3, 11), new Random().Next(0, 600),0);
        MessageBox.Show("32");
        g.DrawString(classen.A.ToString() + "X" + classen.B.ToString(), font, brush, classen.X, classen.Y);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < listan.Count; i++)
        {
            listan[i].Y -= 1;
            Invalidate();

        }    

    }
}
```

All I am trying to do is to make the string `classen.A.ToString() + "X" + classen.B.ToString()` move down... I'm kinda new to C#, and programming in general and would be much appriciated if you would let me know what i'm doing wrong. Thanks!

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Ignore the Lorem ipsum text :p

Comment: What is the interval of your timer set to, and is it enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with a few modifications.  I've commented my changes.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Instantiate an instance of your class.
            Class1 classen = new Class1(new Random().Next(3, 12), new Random().Next(3, 11), new Random().Next(0, 600), 0);
            // Add it to your list.
            listan.Add(classen);
        }

        List<Class1> listan = new List<Class1>();
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Font font = new Font("Arial", 16);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.DeepSkyBlue);

            //MessageBox.Show("32"); <-- don't do this, it will just popup every time your screen is invalidated.

            // Loop through your list.
            for (int i = listan.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                // Determine if your text has scrolled off the top of the screen.
                if (listan[i].Y < -e.Graphics.MeasureString(listan[i].A.ToString(), font).Height)
                {
                    // remove it from the list because it can't be seen anymore, and create a new one.
                    listan.RemoveAt(i);

                    Class1 classen = new Class1(new Random().Next(3, 12), new Random().Next(3, 11), new Random().Next(0, 600), new Random().Next(0, 600));
                    // Add it to your list.
                    listan.Add(classen);

                }
                else
                {
                    // Draw the item, just like you were before.
                    g.DrawString(listan[i].A.ToString() + "X" + listan[i].B.ToString(), font, brush, listan[i].X, listan[i].Y);
                }
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listan.Count; i++)
            {
                listan[i].Y -= 1;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Class1
{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Class1(int a, int b, int x, int y)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value; }
    }
    public int B
    {
        get { return b; }
        set { b = value; }
    }
    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }
    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text isn't moving because `timer1_Tick` invalidates your form `listan.Count` times in a busy loop, then uses the final value of `listan[listan.Count-1].Y` to draw and never changes it.

You need to declare a `Class1 rect` variable once in your form, initialize it once in your constructor, then in your `timer1_Tick` do something like:

```
rect.Y += 1;
Invalidate();
```

Set your timer interval to something like 10 milliseconds. Do not loop in your timer callback. Do not initialize classes in your `Paint` event. You should declare every class you are now initializing in your `Paint` handler in your class and initialize them all, once, in your Form constructor or `OnLoad` handler.

Also, clean up your code; `Class1` is a terrible name, and it looks like it doesn't do anything differently from a `System.Forms.Rectangle`. `A`, `B` and so on are terrible property names.

Do not do anything that might invalidate your form, like calling `MessageBox.Show` in your `Paint` handler.

You need to initialize a single `Random` once in your constructor; `new Random().Next()` does not do what you think it does.

Brushes and fonts are unmanaged resources, you must not reallocate them in your `Paint` handler; initialize them once in your Form constructor or `OnLoad` handler.